# vsphere OSP tools for rhel/centos 6x error downloading

Tags: vmware, centos6, vsphere, vmware-tools

I just want to ask if you guys also experience the same issue as i do.

From time to time vmware OSP  have some issues with the packages. Today is that kind of day.

the Yum update shows that there are updates for the vmware osp repo.

```
    vmware-tools-core                                                 x86_64                               9.4.11-1.el6                                     vmware-tools-collection                               3.9 M
 vmware-tools-esx-kmods                                            x86_64                               9.4.11-1.el6                                     vmware-tools-collection                               2.6 k
 vmware-tools-esx-nox                                              x86_64                               9.4.11-1.el6                                     vmware-tools-collection                               3.0 k
 vmware-tools-foundation                                           x86_64                               9.4.11-1.el6                                     vmware-tools-collection                               213 k
 vmware-tools-guestlib                                             x86_64                               9.4.11-1.el6                                     vmware-tools-collection                                45 k
```

but it wont download them, because there is no file on the website

```
http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5latest/rhel6/x86_64/index.html
```

example of the download error:

```
http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5latest/rhel6/x86_64/vmware-tools-vmxnet-common-9.4.11-5.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5latest/rhel6/x86_64/vmware-tools-vsock-common-9.4.11-5.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

maybe vmware is preparing a new update for vsphere 5.5 ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just check this today.  No issues with the site, but the file you are requesting does not exist.  They either have not posed it or pulled it.

The most resent listed is:

http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5latest/rhel6/x86_64/vmware-tools-vsock-common-9.4.10-5.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: the thing is, that vmware build the meta-base Db with new packages, but for a reason recall the binary's. I believe they are preparing to roll out a new version of vmware-tools..